# Agree with/on/about/to the book - In what scenarios are these correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, descriptive-grammar

Is my current use of these correct:

We agreed on that book. - Eg.: When in a book club you are choosing the book for the next session.

We agreed about that book. -Eg.: When two friends discussed a book and they had the same opinion about it.

We agreed with that book. - Eg.:When two friends discussed a book and they both agreed with the points that were made in the book.

We agreed to that book. - This is not correct. You can only agree to something that you will do.

We agreed the book. This is not correct. You can only agree a price or other detail for something you are negotiating about.

Thank you

Comment: Mostly correct, although 'We agreed to that book' may be used as a deleted form of 'We agreed to your getting that book'. Google "We agreed to one" (glass at dinner, simple rule, one of the tours on offer). Deleted verb: having, adopting, taking, buying, getting, making  etc.

Comment: Thank you. Also, if I want to tell someone that I have agreed on a course of action with somebody, are both of these correct: 'We agreed that I would do that.' or 'We agreed on that I would do that.'

Comment: Only the first. 'We agreed on doing that' is also correct.